# how do I select my npm path?

Tags: linux, node.js, curl, npm, debian

I installed npm in my Debian by using this command

```
<code> curl -L  https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh </code>
```

at the end it says,

```
/usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.12.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
```

It worked

But after that when I run `npm` command in my terminal in shows:

```
root@orvi:/home/orvi# npm
bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

so I assume I have to change the npm path. now I want to know how do I do it ?

Comment: Does it still show that error after launching a new bash session?

Comment: ah. i am so rubbish that I forget to do it. Anyway thanks. yeah now everything is okay.

Comment: No worries.  I get bitten by that frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relaunch bash.  It should correct the path issue.

Comment: To relaunch: exec $SHELL  ($SHELL is the default shell like /bin/bash)